# How to convert a hive string query into abstract syntax tree using Java API?

Tags: java, regex, hadoop, hive, abstract-syntax-tree

I know I can get the AST using the [explain extended command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085119/how-to-convert-a-hive-query-into-abstract-syntax-tree). My question is, how to get the same using the Java API. 
My goal is to get the following data about queries:

- Database source and target (if applied).
- Table source and target (if applied).
- Fields involved in the query.

I know I can get them above data directly from query string using Regex, but I want to use Java API. 
Do you have any other idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Hive Parser for this. It simply takes the query and convert it into AST which is similar explain command. Here is a simple example:

```
ParseDriver pd = new ParseDriver();
ASTNode tree = pd.parse("Select * from table1");
System.out.println(tree.dump());
```

The output for this will be

```
 nil
   TOK_QUERY
      TOK_FROM
         TOK_TABREF
            TOK_TABNAME
               table1
      TOK_INSERT
         TOK_DESTINATION
            TOK_DIR
               TOK_TMP_FILE
         TOK_SELECT
            TOK_SELEXPR
               TOK_ALLCOLREF
   <EOF>
```

Comment: I had forgotten this question, but yes, you are right. Thanks! :)